# preg_match_all doesn't find all matches

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find strings that contain a domain. I have the following pattern:

```
"|s:\\d+:\\\\\"((?:.(?!s:\\d+))+?){$domain}(.+?)\\\\\";|"
```

This (pattern) seems to work, but I get only the first two matches in PHP.

```
$filename = "caciki_tr.sql";
$domain   = "caciki.com.tr";

$domain   = escape($domain, ".");

$content = file_get_contents($filename);

$pattern = "|s:\\d+:\\\\\"((?:.(?!s:\\d+))+?){$domain}(.+?)\\\\\";|";

preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);

function escape($string, $chars) {
    $chars = str_split($chars);
    foreach ($chars as $char) {
        $string = str_replace($char, "\\{$char}", $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => s:121:\"/home/caciki/domains/caciki.com.tr/public_html/wp-content/themes/rafine/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php\";
            [1] => /home/caciki/domains/
            [2] => /public_html/wp-content/themes/rafine/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => s:81:\"/home/caciki/domains/caciki.com.tr/public_html/wp-content/themes/rafine/style.css\";
            [1] => /home/caciki/domains/
            [2] => /public_html/wp-content/themes/rafine/style.css
        )

)
```

I get the all matches (11) only when I tinker with the target file. Something must be breaking the pattern/PHP.

I've tested the same pattern in Python and C#, and they give the correct result:

[image]

[image]

So what's wrong here?

[caciki_tr.sql](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akinuri/dump/master/preg_match_all/caciki_tr.sql) (target file)

---

**Update**: The pattern here is used with different substrings (e.g., domain, url, username, etc.). Not all strings in the target file follows the same pattern. For example, a pattern for URLs should be able to match the following:

```
$url = "http://[DOMAIN_OMITTED]/~caciki";
$pattern = "|s:\d+:\\\\\"([^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*){$url}(.+?)\\\\\";|";
```

```
s:28:\"http://[DOMAIN_OMITTED]/~caciki\";
s:28:\"<a href=\"http://[DOMAIN_OMITTED]/~caciki\">some page</a>\";
```

In short, there might not be a string between the `s:28:\"` and the substring ($url), or after the substring. So it should be optional.

Comment: Your file is too big, I suspect. [Here](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9697-PHP-Search-large-files-that-would-not-fit-in-memory.html) is an interesting solution  in case you want to work with large files. BTW, `(?:.(?!s:\d+))+?` is very inefficient, you may use `[^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*` to streamline it a bit.

Comment: Huh, it worked. I changed `(?:.(?!s:\d+))+?` into `[^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*`, and now I get 11 matches... So you're saying it might be related to the filesize. I suppose, as the filesize increases, performance decreases, and at some point it fails?... I was using this just for debug purposes, and your suggestion is enough for now, but I'll definitely take a look at that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current pattern is rather inefficient as it contains a corrupt [**"tempered greedy token"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970), `(?:.(?!s:\d+))+?`. This is a very inefficient construct that should be "unwrapped" if you want to use such a regex in production.

You may use `[^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*` instead of it:

```
"|s:\d+:\\\\\"([^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*)$domain(.+?)\\\\\";|'
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `[^s]*` - 0+ chars other than `s`
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group repeating...

  - `s(?!:\d)` - `s` not followed with `:` + a digit
  - `[^s]*` - 0+ chars other than `s`
- `)*` - zero or more times.

Note that if you plan to work with big files make sure your patterns are as efficient as possible. Also, [here](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9697-PHP-Search-large-files-that-would-not-fit-in-memory.html) is an interesting solution in case you want to work with large files (`pcregrep` is a very fast tool).

Comment: I've added an update to my question regarding the pattern change. It seems to fail in some cases, e.g. this is a match: `s:28:\"http://[DOMAIN_OMITTED]/~caciki\";s:13:\"image_classes\"`.

Comment: @akinuri `[^s]*(?:s(?!:\d)[^s]*)*` can match an empty string. I think you have a problem with your `escape` method. Replace it with a mere `$domain   = preg_quote($domain, "|");`. Besides, in the question you pass `$domain` to the pattern, in the edit part, it is `$url`. Please make sure you are not mixing up variables.

Comment: See: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZrfnjH/1). When I debug these serialized variables (strings), I need to be able to get the surrounding strings (if there are any). Serialized string pattern is like this: `s:[STRING_LENGTH]:\"[STRING]\"` and `STRING` could be `str + substr (domain, url, etc) + str`  or just the substring. You get the idea. In the regex demo, the second match captures more than necessary.

Comment: Thank you. You've been a great help.